# How can I know what prevents efficient lower level code when using FunctionCompile?

Tags: compile, function-compile

When using the old [Compile](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Compile.html?q=Compile), I can use [CompilePrint](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Compile/ref/CompilePrint.html) and ensure the resulting CompiledFunction doesn't use MainEvaluate. If MainEvaluate isn't used, the CompiledFunction is efficient. How do we know if [FunctionCompile](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionCompile.html?q=FunctionCompile) can make efficient code, and where the problem is when it can't?

**Update**

Below I see that some things the prevent an efficient result in Failure and a Message.

[image: FunctionCompile Fails]
So should I expect that FunctionCompile was able to convert the program to lower level code if I don't get Failue and a message?